# Angular force pipe transform from within pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Suppose I have my own pipe which looks like this (dummy example)

```
@Pipe({ name: 'myPipe' })
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  private lastKey: string;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    myService.onSomeVariableChange.subscribe((r) => {
      console.log('now i should be transformed again');
    });
  }

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) {
    return `${value} ${this.myService.someVariable}`;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span> {{ 'SomeText' | myPipe }} </span>
```

I simply return the input with a suffix which is variable. The pipe knows the variable has been changed through the event `onSomeVariableChange`. The Angular framework should now call `transform` again.

But since my pipe is pure (and I really don't want it to be impure) and since my input does not change (only an external variable), the transform is not automatically called.

How can I, from within my pipe, force this method to be called? Note that this is a **DUMMY EXAMPLE**. The real scenario is a lot more complex, so the ideal solution would not be to circumvent this non-existing scenario. The ideal solution would be a way to force `transform` to be called again.

Answer (score 1):

If the pipe is `impure` it will update on every change detection cycle - but you could try triggering change detection yourself only when the data updates e.g

```js
constructor(private myService: MyService, cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    myService.onSomeVariableChange.subscribe((r) => {
      console.log('now i should be transformed again');
      cd.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

I haven't tested this, so not fully sure if it will run the pipe transform again - you may also need to add in `cd.markForCheck()`

Comment: I tried with both `detectChanges` and `markForCheck` but unfortunately this does not apply on pipes.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use pipe here, instead, i would use a custom directive like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyMagicDir]'
})
export class MyMagicDirDirective {

  @Input() appMyMagicDir: string;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private myService: MyService) {
    myService.onSomeVariableChange.subscribe(res => {
      elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = `${appMyMagicDir}${res}`
    } )
   }

}
```

then on your  element just apply the directive like this:

```
<span [appMyMagicDir]="someTextVar"></span>
```

or alternatively and probably simpler -

```
<span>{{SomeTextVar}}{{myService.onSomeVariableChange | async}}</span>
```

Comment: [1/2] Thanks. This comes very close and would be usable for us. But the latter which stil uses a pipe would not be possible. This pipe is to be used in LOTS of places and the variable change even in my dummy example is more complex. It filters out using rxjs for certain prefixes etc... 
Too bad we cannot force a transform on the pipe as that would be our ideal scenario

Comment: [2/2] But the directive scenario assumes the text to be set inside a `span`, `p`, ... Whereas a pipe can be used in a lot more cases. E.g. `<button [matTooltip]={{ 'someText' | myPipe  }}</button>`. I do not see this working with a directive