angular impure pipe triggered only on service changes
Am implementing a service named MyService (singleton) which has an attribute called config, and a pipe named MyPipe which should only be re-evaluated when MyService.config  (not the input into the pipe!) is changed (the transform function actually uses MyService.config in the transformation logic). Is it possible at all in angular?
I understood that pure pipes are only re-evaluated when the input is changed and impure pipes are re-evaluated on every change detection cycle. What I want to achieve is a pipe that is re-evaluated NOT when the input is changed, and also NOT on every change detection cycle, but when an unrelated condition happens as mentioned above.
I actually tried to add a ChangeDetectorRef but didn't succeed, which let me to ask if it's possible at all. Any hints would be very much appreciated!

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72689506

What you are asking for is not possible. Either the pipe is pure and the transform function is executed only when the value (or arguments) change, or the pipe is impure and is executed on every change detection cycle. There is nothing in between.
As a workaround, you can add the config as a pipe parameter, but this makes the usage of the pipe harder.
@Pipe({ name: myPipe })
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: unknown, config: MyConfig) {
    // pipe logic
  }
}

{{ 'someValue' | myPipe: myService.config }}


Thanks for confirming my speculation. MyService is actually TranslateService, config is selectedLangue, and myPipe is tranlate. I think it's such a usecase that angular should support. How to implement this use case in angular? I also tried implementing the interpolation Service.translate but discovered that it was called unnecessarily too often while TranslateService.selectedLanguage isn't changed.

There is a feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15041 But it was closed in favor of computed signals. So it's unlikely that such feature will be added to Angular pipes, although your use case sounds reasonable.
